# Asp.net add script to page header from string variable

Tags: asp.net

I need to display ADS from an AD server to my ASP.NET pages. I am storing the scripts (as part of my settings) in the db. How can I add the script to the page header at runtime after loading it into a string variable? Here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">var proto = "http:"; if (document.location.protocol == "https:") { proto = "https:" }var z=document.createElement("script");z.type="text/javascript";z.async=true;z.src= proto + "//static.adserver.net/ad.js";var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s);</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ad = ad || {};
ad.run = ad.run || [];
ad.run.push(function() {
<!-- load placement for account: youraccount, site: yoursite, size: 500x120 - 500x120-->
ad_add_placement(1234, 99999, "abc12345", 12);
ad_load();
});</script>
```

I've seen examples where you can load the script without the tags e.g.

```
//HtmlGenericControl HTMLControl = new HtmlGenericControl() { TagName = "script" };    //HTMLControl.Attributes.Add("type", @"text\javascript");
//HTMLControl.InnerText = myScript;
//this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(HTMLControl);
```

In my case, however, I would prefer to keep my script the same as I receive from the AD server without altering it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) to add a script block to the top of your page.

Comment: I tried that but it keeps going to the bottom of the page. I am inheriting from a Master page....would that make a difference?

Comment: I don't know how inheriting from a Master page affects it, but you can also try some variants like [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) or [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) if you have a ScriptManager in your page.